# Android AlarmClock source for 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to find the source for the built-in alarm clock for Android 2.3.3.

I checked her: git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock
But that is for Android 4.0 and up.

Where can I find a previous version?

Comment: hello sir, did u find code u wher looking for ??? i followed tat link but did't get how to download it ?..if u have working clock code can u please mail to `kiran3545@gmail.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open your link there is a list of branches on the left top corner. You can select `gingerbread` there.

You can clone only `gingerbread` branch of DeskClock's sources like this:

```
git clone -b gingerbread https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock
```

Comment: just check may be u sent wrong link , because i did't fing anything there

Comment: Link worked perfectly for me. You have to instal a git client to get it work.